# String !equals of edittext not working

Tags: java, android

With the help of cursor c and c1 ,I am checking the two database with edittext.If its not equal,then it move to NotFound activity.

Below I am posted the code:

```
if (c.getCount() > 0) {

.....
....
}
 else if(c1.getCount()>-1){
....
....
}

 else{

       if(!(editText.getText().toString()).equals("c") && (!(editText.getText().toString().equals("c1")))) {   ---->not working


       Intent i2=new Intent(Plate.this,NotFound.class);
       startActivity(i2);

      }
     }
```

My only problem is `if(!(editText.getText().toString()).equals("c") && (!(editText.getText().toString().equals("c1"))))` is not working.I am not sure what's wrong in that.

Comment: The expression in your `if` statement seems a little confusing.

Comment: You want to check if the content of the editText is not c or c1?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi no if c and c1 is not equal to edittext value I entered then move to new activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in your `if` statement seems a little muddled as there is an extra parentheses in your statement that changes how it works:

```
!(editText.getText().toString()).equals("c") && (!(editText.getText().toString().equals("c1")))
```

If we simplify it, calling the first expression `editText.getText().toString()` a new variable `a` (notice the lack of the `equals()`) and the second part `editText.getText().toString().equals("c1")` a new variable `b`, we are left with `((!a).equals("c") && !b)` which doesn't really make sense.

I believe you want to replace `a` with `editText.getText().toString().equals("c")` and use `!a && !b` instead, which is

```
(!editText.getText().toString().equals("c") && !editText.getText().toString().equals("c1"))
```

That statement will return `true` when the `EditText` does not contain `"c"` or `"c1"`.

Comment: Actually @Richard wrote : `!(xx).equals("c") && (!(xxx))` and not `!(a && !b)`
And you corrected `(!xx).equals("c") && ! xxx`. so you're wrong putting  `!` right before a string

Comment: notice the parenthesis. He actually wrote `!a && !b`.

Comment: Man I double checked. `![editText.getText().toString()].equals("c") && (![editText.getText().toString().equals("c1")])` : the first [] block is `xx` the second is `xxx` I wrote in my comment.

Comment: *facepalm* I see the problem now. Thanks

Comment: @Richard I have amended my answer

Comment: Working fine thank you.I done wrong with looping if else.thats why didn't get an expected result.sorry

Comment: Thank you @yiabiten, you were right! Will double check next time - thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are confused with `!` statements and parenthesis then I can simplify for you

```
String s =editText.getText().toString();
if(s.equals("c") || s.equals("c1")) { 
 //Do nothing
} else {
   Intent i2=new Intent(Plate.this,NotFound.class);
   startActivity(i2);
  }
```

Comment: That will always return `false`, how can a String ever equal both "c" _and_ "c1"

Comment: Bad practice. Always check that "c1".equals(s) to protect against NPE if s is null. Where have you learned to code ?

Answer (score 0):

!(editText.getText().toString()).equals("c") is looking ok u can try

!(editText.getText().toString()).**equalsIgnoreCase**("c")